# Передача изображения из нативной библиотеки в Android

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

Подскажите, как передать изображение из библиотеки на C++ в приложение под андроидом.

Пишу простой html рендер: https://www.livecoding.tv/video/simple-html-render-c/ . Во второй части хочу запустить его под андроидом.

Самый простой вариант передачи изображения:

```
String img = Render("index.html"); 
Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap(img);
```

Через файл. Но это костыль и так делать не надо.

Как реализовать передачу изображения?

На мой взгляд самым простым способом будет возвращать само изображение, а не ссылку на него. Как его загрузить в Bitmap?

Не самым простым способом будет формирование изображение из C++.
Есть пример вызова Bitmap.createBitmap() - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677092/creating-an-android-graphics-bitmap-from-c , но это недостаточно для решения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Верните из JNI массив байтов, а потом грузите на стороне Java картинку из этого массива, как хотите.

```
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL get_bitmap(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring str) {
    const char *nativeString = env->GetStringUTFChars(str, 0); // "index.html"
    char* data = ;//указатель на данные, берите их откуда хотите
    size_t size = ; // размер данных

    jbyteArray result = env->NewByteArray(size);

    if (result == NULL) {
        return NULL; //  out of memory error thrown
    }

    env->SetByteArrayRegion(result, 0, size, data);
    return result;
}

// Регистрация нативных методов в JVM
static JNINativeMethod methods[] = {
    {"getBitmap", "(Ljava/lang/String;)[B", (void *)get_bitmap},
};

jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *)
{
    JNIEnv *env;
    if (vm->GetEnv(reinterpret_cast<void **>(&env), JNI_VERSION_1_4) != JNI_OK)
        return JNI_FALSE;

    jclass clazz = env->FindClass("com/example/MyCoolClass");
    if (clazz ) {
         if (env->RegisterNatives(clazz, methods, sizeof(methods)/sizeof(methods[0])) < 0)
             return JNI_FALSE;
    }

    return JNI_VERSION_1_4;
}
```

На стороне Java:

```
package com.example;

class MyCoolClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String img = Render("index.html"); 
       byte[] bytes = getBitmap(img);
       Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    }
    private static native byte[] getBitmap(String arg);
}
```

Надеюсь, идея вам понятна. Если вопрос производительности для вас критичен, почитайте [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709210/jni-passing-large-amounts-of-data-between-java-and-native-code).

Comment: В каком виде передавать данные? Как указать ширину и высоту картинки, количество бит? А если я передам jpeg?

Comment: передавайте в формате bmp. Нужно будет заполнить структуру заголовка BMP файла (то есть по сути вы должны воссоздать в памяти bmp файл. это делается элементарно) .  BitmapFactory сама может  определить формат данных и размер изображений

Comment: Можете передавать в каком угодно формате, хоть jpeg, хоть png,.

Comment: Все получилось https://www.livecoding.tv/video/very-simple-html-render-2-c-android/ . Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

По моему опыту несмотря на одно копирование данных, самый быстрый способ (если C-функция работает с форматом raw). К сожалению я не нашёл способа совсем без копирования.

Часть класса java:

```
native ByteBuffer newBitmap(int width, int height, int bpp);
native void freeBitmap(ByteBuffer buf);
public static final Config[] colormode= new Config[]{null, Config.ALPHA_8, Config.RGB_565, null, Config.ARGB_8888};
public Bitmap getBitmap(int width, height, bytePerPixel) {
    Bitmap b=Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, colormode[bytePerPixel]); // подготавливаем место под картинку
    ByteBuffer bbuf= newBitmap(width, height, bytePerPixel); // получаем данные из C
    if(bbuf!=null) {
        if(bbuf.remaining() > bitmap.getRowBytes()*bitmap.getHeight()) // если картинка оказалась длиннее
            bbuf.limit(bitmap.getRowBytes()*bitmap.getHeight());
        bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(bbuf); // копируем буфер в картинку
        freeBitmap(bbuf); // освобождаем буфер
        return bitmap;
    }else return null;
}
```

C++:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL
Java_org_myclass_newBitmap(JNIEnv * env, jobject _this, jint width, jint height, jint bpp)
{
    unsigned char *pix = malloc(width*height*bpp);
    if(!pix) return 0;
    for(int i=0; i< width; i++)
       for(int j=0; j< height; i++)
          for(int k=0; k< bpp; k++) { // как-то заполняем
             pix[j*bpp*width+i*bpp+k]= k==3? 255 : i*k+j*(2-k);
          }
    return env->NewDirectByteBuffer(pix, width*height*bpp);
}

extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_org_myclass_freeBitmap(JNIEnv * env, jobject _this, jobject bbuf)
{
    free(env->GetDirectBufferAddress(bbuf));
}

jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved)
{
    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}
```